# Converting the regular expression in java to golang. Correct me

Tags: java, regex, go

Java Regular expression:

```
str.replaceFirst("(\\p{XDigit}{8})(\\p{XDigit}{4})(\\p{XDigit}{4})(\\p{XDigit}{4})(\\p{XDigit}+)", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5")
```

What I have tried in Go:

```
re:=regexp.MustCompile("(\\p{XDigit}{8})(\\p{XDigit}{4})(\\p{XDigit}{4})(\\p{XDigit}{4})(\\p{XDigit}+)")

repStr := "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5"

str1:=re.ReplaceAllString(someString,repStr)
```

It says that the XDigit is an unknown character category

Comment: You can check whether the regex is correct or not and it flow of control in [this](https://regexper.com) link.

Comment: according [documentation](https://golang.org/s/re2syntax#user-content-ascii) you can use `[[:xdigit:]]` (instead of `\\p{XDigit}`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is just one (half) line, you can integrate it in yours

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Ok, see, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In [Java regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the `\p{XDigit}` is just a shorthand for `[0-9a-fA-F]`:

```
POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)
\p{Lower}               A lower-case alphabetic character: [a-z]
\p{Upper}               An upper-case alphabetic character:[A-Z]
\p{ASCII}               All ASCII:[\x00-\x7F]
\p{Alpha}               An alphabetic character:[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]
\p{Digit}               A decimal digit: [0-9]
\p{Alnum}               An alphanumeric character:[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]
\p{Punct}               Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;?@[\]^_`{|}~
\p{Graph}               A visible character: [\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]
\p{Print}               A printable character: [\p{Graph}\x20]
\p{Blank}               A space or a tab: [ \t]
\p{Cntrl}               A control character: [\x00-\x1F\x7F]
\p{XDigit}              A hexadecimal digit: [0-9a-fA-F]
\p{Space}               A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

The same `[0-9a-fA-F]` character class can be expressed with a [`[[:xdigit:]]` in Go regex](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax#user-content-ascii).

You may write the Go pattern like

```
re:=regexp.MustCompile("([[:xdigit:]]{8})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]+)")
```

Or,

```
re:=regexp.MustCompile("([0-9a-fA-F]{8})([0-9a-fA-F]{4})([0-9a-fA-F]{4})([0-9a-fA-F]{4})([0-9a-fA-F]+)")
```

You may see the [online Go regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/hQ9K74/1) and here is [a Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/j_9QdLesSxK):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const sample = `0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f 0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f0a1f`

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`([[:xdigit:]]{8})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]+)`)
    repl := `$1-$2-$3-$4-$5`
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(sample, repl))
}
```

Result: `0a1f0a1f-0a1f-0a1f-0a1f-0a1f0a1f 0a1f0a1f-0a1f-0a1f-0a1f-0a1f0a1f`.

Note that if you need to replace *only the first occurrence* (as in Java, you are using `String#replaceFirst`), you will probably want to match the whole string with `.*?` before the pattern you need to replace, and then `.*` after it to match the rest of the string, capture them and adjust the replacement string to contain the placeholders for these two additional parts of the string:

```
re:=regexp.MustCompile("^(.*?)([[:xdigit:]]{8})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]{4})([[:xdigit:]]+)(.*)$")
repStr := "$1$2-$3-$4-$5-$6$7"
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ9K74/2).

Comment: Please consider taking into account @Carlos Heuberger comment.

Comment: no need to post it myself.... not sure, but `[[:xdigit:]]` is just one *token*, `[a-fA-F0-9]` can be a bit more complicated (implementation-wise) and the later one is more *traditional*, should work no matter which regular expression